# JS: if innerhtml is empty, change innerhtml to something. HOW?

Tags: javascript, html

i'm new to js
so i have a simple html element that has contenteditable="true" which i'm using as an input box.
i want the innerhtml to change to "CAN'T BE EMPTY" when the user has typed nothing in the input box ( " " )
and apparently it doesn't work, any tips on how i can do it?
this is my code (which is not working):

HTML:
`<p contenteditable="true" id="myparagraph">Input</p>`

JS:

```
 if(document.getElementById("myparagraph").innerHTML == ""){
 document.getElementById("myparagraph").innerHTML = "CAN'T BE EMPTY";}
```

i've also tried using the LENGTH property, but didn't work either:

```
    var plength = document.getElementById("myparagraph").innerHTML;
        var plength2 = plength.length;
if(plength2 == 0){
     document.getElementById("myparagraph").innerHTML = "CAN'T BE EMPTY";}
```

Comment: Why don't you log what it is?

Answer (score 2):

It's not empty. It's got a value of `Input` according to your HTML.

If you want to change the value when the user edits, you need to attach an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```js
document.getElementById('myparagraph').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  if (e.target.textContent.trim() === '') {
    e.target.textContent = 'Cannot be empty';
  }
})
```

```html
<p contenteditable="true" id="myparagraph">Input</p>
```

Note that I changed the logic from using `innerHTML` to using `textContent` because otherwise remaining empty HTML tags can prevent the warning from triggering. (Firefox, for example inserts a `<br>` when there is no content.)

Comment: This code doesn't display the warning message.

Comment: @Andy You have to edit the text. Delete `Input` and the message will be displayed.

Comment: Weird. I'm FF101. The warning doesn't show.

Comment: Yeah, works fine in Chrome though.

Comment: @Andy Firefox inserts a `<br>` when the content is emptied. Updated my answer. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to display the warning anywhere than the content of the element you're trying to check. Add an event listener to the paragraph element. In the handler get the `textContent` from the element, and then show/hide the warning depending on whether that text is empty.

```js
const para = document.querySelector('#para');
const warning = document.querySelector('#warning');

para.addEventListener('input', handleInput, false);

function handleInput() {
  const text = this.textContent;
  warning.textContent = text ? '' : 'Cannot be empty';
}
```

```css
#para { border: 1px solid #565656; padding: 0.5em; }
#warning { color: red; }
```

```html
<p contenteditable="true" id="para">Input</p>
<p id="warning"></p>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, it works. though i added an interval that changes the innertext to the length value every 0.05 seconds, so for a moment i see "EMPTY" on my element and then it turns to "1" which i think is because it never gets EMPTY and even though there are no characters inside the innerhtml , there's always 1 character inside for some reason